# What does it mean when the sentence take the form of '~ , meaning ~'?

Tags: present-participles, participle-clauses

I often see sentences that take the form of *". . . , doing . . . "*.
I'm not sure what exactly it means.
I want to do some research for this sentence pattern, but I even don't know  the keyword to search.

I researched in a corpus to find some examples, here are some example I found.

> A majority of the revenue is still " dedicated " to this purpose , **meaning** it goes directly to the federal Highway Trust Fund.

> As they did so, the teacher listened in on their conversations , **providing** hints as they interacted.

So what does this pattern means? And if I want some more information, what is the correct keyword to research?

Thanks!!

Comment: It's  a gerund-participle clause postmodifying the noun phrase head.

Answer (score 3):

I don't agree with user178049 that the participial clauses mentioned in the OP postmodify the noun phrase head. This will be usually the case when there is **no comma** between the noun and the "ing"- phrase, in which case the "ing"- phrase will be a reduced relative clause:

- He opened the boxes **containing** the gifts. (= He opened the boxes *that contained* the gifts.)

After a comma, participial clauses will usually refer to the preceding **clause**, to indicate a simultaneous or subsequent action, or as a sentence relative:

- A majority of the revenue is still "dedicated" to this purpose, **meaning** (= which means / and this means) it goes directly to the federal Highway Trust Fund.
- As they did so, the teacher listened in on their conversations, **providing** (= and (the teacher) provided) hints as they interacted.

Participial clauses can also be used at the beginning of a sentence to indicate an action or event previous to that expressed by the main verb of the sentence:

- **Knowing** he had no way out, he decided to give up.

Comment: I think you are right. Glad that I didn't post an answer.